# New activity notification inserts new questions into currently focused tab

Tags: bug, status-completed

I don't know if this is by design, but when there is new activity in a question and this new notification appears:
[image]

The new questions will be inserted in the currently focused tab. Even if it isn't the *active* tab.
[image]

Comment: Now that's a nice discovery, of a sad bug... :D

Comment: Is this is a new feature?

Comment: @iglvzx [I think it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fix will roll out with the next build.  If you aren't on the active tab then you will not receive updates.

Comment: 2 more: When the questions are inserted, their vote count is always 0, even if the question has already been voted on. Also, new questions are treated as *active* questions, but if you refresh the page, new questions will have moved to the *Newest* tab.

Comment: Not sure if this is a regression or not, but I am getting this same bug right now.

Comment: We did a reset of our socket server.  There may be an edge case around that - just refresh or F5 and it should go away.